# Overlapping fragments after restarting the application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

My android application consists of fragments. 
In transitions between tracks using the method `add()`.

If you perform the following sequence:

1. Go to any new piece of the application
2. Close my application
3. Log into another application for 20 minutes.
4. Re-open my app

It shows a fragment of which is registered in the parent Activiti in `onCreate()`, on top of an old fragment.

How to fix the overlay?

Comment: Post your onCreate method. This happened to me before but I'm not quite sure if I remember what I did to fix it.

Comment: @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

   mainFrag = new Main();
   fTrans.add(R.id.container, mainFrag, "main");
   fTrans.commit();
}